Managing Helm Chart Versions for Multiple Environments
Here's the docker, helm, and environment setup:

Docker images for both integration and release branches
an umbrella helm chart for all of our microservices
dev, test, and prod environments

For dev, I only want to deploy integration images, and for test/prod, I only want to deploy release images. The correct tag for the Docker image will be contained in its corresponding sub-chart. If I am trying to automate deployments into each environment using ArgoCD, how do I version my Helm charts?
A couple ideas I've come up with:

Maintain the dev environment as a manual set up where developers increment the images through Argo manifests
Maintain an dev version and a prod version of the umbrella chart
a. dev  - 0.0.1
b. prod - 1.0.0

How do others handle this scenario?

Using TBD - Trunk-based Development - then you're essentially promoting same images from one environment to the next. See example how we do it - https://worklifenotes.com/2023/05/12/how-to-promote-software-to-production-with-reliza-hub/

You could resolve this with semantic versioning ranges (https://semver.org).
For example, in test/prod you would specify ~2.0.0 and always bump the patch version: 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, and so on. 2.1 would not be picked up automatically.
For dev you would specify ^2.0. All the above versions would be picked up, as well as 2.1, 2.2, etc.
This way, all patch and minor version bumps get picked by dev, but only patch version bumps get picked by test/prod.
See also: https://devhints.io/semver
